# How to modify WHEN a custom model binder gets implemented

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom model binder that works just the way I want it to.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

Problem is that I only want to implement it on a needs basis and DO NOT want to overrule the default model binder.

One piece of research turned up the idea of adding a specified Type key to direct when the model binder is executed (see below).

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List), new CustomModelBinder());
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me unless I set the DefaultBinder to my CustomModelBinder.

Is it possible to keep the default model binder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to set a certain custom model binder globally. You can set it per Action method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]SomeModel m){
    //...
}
```

It will then be applicable only in the above scenario. In every other `Action` method using a binding to `SomeModel`, but with no `ModelBinder` attribute applied it will use the default model binder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately when I try this my CustomModelBinder still does not get invoked unless I override the default ModelBinder globaly.

Comment: Looks like I found the problem! There were a few other properties I needed to bind inside hidden elements in order to get it to work. That was my mess up. Your solution was exactly what I needed, thanks again!